# Случайный неравномерный выбор элемента из массива

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть массив из N  элементов, и массив из коэффициентов вероятности выпадения каждого элемента. Как можно реализовать выбор случайного элемента из этого массива?

Я реализовал это так, но думаю, что это не очень хорошо.

```
$items = array(10, 20, 30);
$factors = array(0.2, 0.5, 0.3);

$values = array();
foreach ($factors as $indexFactors => $valueFactors)
{
    $values[$indexFactors] = summ($factors, $indexFactors);
}

echo $items[ getIndex($values) ];

function getIndex($values)
{
    $random = rand(0, 10) / 10;
    foreach ($values as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($random <= $value) return $key;
    }
}

function summ($array, $index)
{
    if ($index) {
        return $array[$index] + summ($array, $index - 1);
    } else {
        return $array[$index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Только учтите, что сумма элементов array д.б. 1 и они должны быть упорядочены по возрастанию.

Неплохо бы проверять эти условия, скажем, при первом вызове.

Comment: Про еденицу я знаю, так и сделал. А почему по возрастанию?

Comment: Упорядоченность роди не играет благодаря равномерному распределению.

Answer (score 3):

Я не на php пишу, но идею предложил бы следующую:  
Я бы на твоем месте реализовал генератор случайных чисел, подчиняющихся твоему распределению (factors) 
Смотри, у тебя есть функция random, которая умеет генерировать равномерное распределение на отрезке [0,1]. С помощью это можешь подчинить равномерное распределение любому другому, в частности, твоему.
Например, ты сгенерировал случайную величину - дальше просто насчитываешь сумму по своему распределению, пока она не станет больше этой случайно величины. То, сколько раз ты складывал элементы из массива вероятностей и даст индекс соответствующего элемента из items .
Пример:
prob = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5 0,3}
val = {10, 20, 30, 40}
Генерируешь случайную величину от 0 до 1- пусть, например она равна 0.7
Дальше насчитываешь такую сумму: 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.5 = 0.8 > 0.7 Стало быть индекс элемента = 2, т.е. 30

Comment: Спасибо! =) Но мой код как раз так и делает )

Comment: Мельком код просмотрел, что-то похожее увидел, но не вглядывался сильно... А прием-то стандартный)    
Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

1. Есть массив вероятностей: `array(0.2, 0.5, 0.3);`
2. Генерим N чисел от 1 до 100, и умножаем на вероятности, получаем что-то типа:

   ```
   array(0.2 * 56, 0.5 * 23, 0.3 * 43); => array(11,2, 11,5, 12,9)
   ```
3. Выбираем самое большое число после умножения. Если есть одинаковые можно рандомить среди них на равных правах.